# Refusal on UK visitor Visa

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, sri-lankan-citizens

I am Sri Lankan citizen. I have been working as an Engineer for the last 2 years in Sri Lanka and joined my most recent company 6 months ago. I recently applied for UK tourist visa and got a refusal.

I wanted to visit London as it was one of my dream destinations. I was refused on three facts.

1. the origin of income is not clear. That may be because I was working remotely and they paid me via petty cash rather than pay slips.
2. November salary is higher as I joined 5 days before the payroll date and that amount is higher than what I stated in the form.
3. I don't have any property or family ties to Sri Lanka.

Apart from my salary, there are no other deposits in my account. I am unmarried and don't own any assets.

I want address these issues.

My company is ready to provide a justification from their end on the petty cash/salary slips issue and they are happy to even provide full sponsorship as I  worked very hard during the last 6 months.

I have a bond of 2500 dollar with my company as I received some training so I will definitely return to the country after the visit.

Previously I applied saying that I am covering my expenses myself. One of my friends sent me an invitation letter (no sponsor letters). My passport is not a fresh passport i have stamps for few countries on tourist visas.

I am planing to reapply but really am worried because I would not like to get a second refusal. As I am getting a sponsorship now from the company will that make improve the application or seem suspicious? My company is very stable and reputed people have been to UK before for training.

Comment: @Dinuk You might be able to address the proof/provenance of funds problem (although I don’t think sponsorship from your employer is the way to do it, it’s better if you meet the eligibility criteria in your own right) but that still leaves the lack of ties. Sometimes reapplying quickly after a refusal can count against you because it can look as if you are overly keen to get to the UK.

Comment: @traveller Can i use my company bond as  a tie ?(2500 dollar and bonded to one year ) last time i didnt show it. kindly adivice  :(. also i have enough fund myslef the rejection was about the origin of income

Comment: You’re likely to get a second successive refusal given your profile. I wouldn’t recommend reapplying for at least another year and then put together a solid application without any red flags.

Comment: @cHiEfImmigrationvIoLaTer will this impact for schengen visa as well if i go a vacation on a Europe country.? becuase i need to get the leave before august as i will be busy after that.

Comment: @Dinuk Having a successful travel history (i.e., getting visas and then returning home on time) is useful to later visa applications, as prior conduct is seen as indicative of future conduct. I agree with the other comments that you should not immediately reapply for a visa to the UK. Remember too that there are lots of travel destinations other than the UK and the EU, and developing a successful travel history in other countries will ultimately strengthen your UK and EU applications.

Answer (score -1):

same problem and 2 tips or rejection reasons you have mentioned was faced with a friend , but he tried again with a proof and he take care about being one month high and one month down .specially if your work is stable and salary too

i think you should to try one more time and you are gonna get it . its a small mistake and dont try to show something not normal .

thanks